# Got error message when run a simple tensorflow code after building Tensorflow c++ GPU version

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Hey I'm using tensorflow c++. I built tensorflow with [this](https://medium.com/vitrox-publication/deep-learning-frameworks-tensorflow-build-from-source-on-windows-python-c-cpu-gpu-d3aa4d0772d8). I built a GPU version. When I run the sample code, I got many errors.
I built tensorflow r2.5 and protobuf-3.9.2.
code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tensorflow/core/framework/graph.pb.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/session.h>
#include <tensorflow/core/public/version.h>
int main() {
    std::cout << tf_git_version() << std::endl;
    std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(tensorflow::NewSession({}));
}
```

errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TF_savedmodel, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>Source.cpp
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value.pb.h(687,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def.pb.h(97,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(300,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(332,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(587,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(590,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(621,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\function.pb.h(624,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\Half.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (950). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\BFloat16.h(1,1): warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (950). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\Eigen\src\Core\arch\Default\GenericPacketMathFunctions.h(678,1): warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (950). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\Eigen\src\Core\products\GeneralBlockPanelKernel.h(2065,1): warning C4819: The file contains a character that cannot be represented in the current code page (950). Save the file in Unicode format to prevent data loss
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tstring.h(350,40): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tstring.h(350): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tstring.h(350,56): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(383,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(382,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(383): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(383,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(383,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(384,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(384,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(384): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(384,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(384,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(385,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(385,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(385): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(385,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(385,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(386,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(386,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(386): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(386,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(386,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(387,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(387,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(387): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(387,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(387,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(388,1): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(388,1): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(388): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(388,1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\default\logging.h(388,1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\error_codes.pb.h(80,92): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\error_codes.pb.h(80,92): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\error_codes.pb.h(80): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\error_codes.pb.h(80,92): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\error_codes.pb.h(81,92): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(106,67): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(106,67): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(106): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(106,67): error C2737: 'protected: static __int64 const tensorflow::TensorShapeRep::kMaxRep16': constexpr object must be initialized
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(106,67): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(107,67): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(107,67): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(107): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(107,67): error C2737: 'protected: static __int64 const tensorflow::TensorShapeRep::kMaxRep32': constexpr object must be initialized
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(107,67): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(108,72): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(108,72): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(108): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(108,72): error C2737: 'protected: static unsigned short const tensorflow::TensorShapeRep::kUnknownRep16': constexpr object must be initialized
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(108,72): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(109,72): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(109,72): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(109): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(109,72): error C2737: 'protected: static unsigned int const tensorflow::TensorShapeRep::kUnknownRep32': constexpr object must be initialized
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_shape.h(109,72): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\src\Tensor\Tensor.h(76,1): warning C4554: '&': check operator precedence for possible error; use parentheses to clarify precedence
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\src\Tensor\TensorMap.h(43): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::Tensor<T,1,1,int>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\tensor_types.h(105): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<T,1,1,int>,16,Eigen::MakePointer>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=float
1>        ]
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(106,109): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(106,109): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(106): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(106,109): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(107,109): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(133,123): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(133,123): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(133): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(133,123): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(134,123): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(158,94): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(158,94): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(158): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(158,94): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\google\protobuf\type.pb.h(159,94): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tensor_coding.h(47,38): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tensor_coding.h(47): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\platform\tensor_coding.h(47,62): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\framework\step_stats.pb.h(1180,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\cluster.pb.h(97,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\verifier_config.pb.h(72,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\verifier_config.pb.h(72,131): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\verifier_config.pb.h(72): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\verifier_config.pb.h(72,131): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\verifier_config.pb.h(73,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(94,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(94,131): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(94): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(94,131): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(95,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(120,137): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(120,137): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(120): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(120,137): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(121,137): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(146,153): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(146,153): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(146): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(146,153): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(147,153): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(176,139): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(176,139): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(176): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(176,139): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(177,139): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\rewriter_config.pb.h(543,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(156,133): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(156,133): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(156): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(156,133): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(157,133): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(183,151): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(183,151): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(183): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(183,151): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(184,151): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(211,173): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(211,173): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(211): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(211,173): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(212,173): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(238,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'min'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(238,131): error C2589: '(': illegal token on right side of '::'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(238): error C2062: type 'unknown-type' unexpected
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(238,131): error C3805: 'type': unexpected token, expected either '}' or a ','
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(239,131): warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'max'
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(1951,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(3797,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(3800,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(3831,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config.pb.h(3834,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
1>D:\tf_model\TF_savedmodel\include\tensorflow\core\public\session_options.h(62,2): warning C4091: '__declspec(dllimport)': ignored on left of 'tensorflow::SessionOptions' when no variable is declared
1>Done building project "TF_savedmodel.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Some said this happened because of "Windows.h", but I didn't saw such a include command in these header files. Should I edit some of those files?
If someone could tell me how to solve that, it will be nice.

[solved] just add () to following files which using std::XXX::min/ max().
[image]
[image]

Comment: Put `#define NOMINMAX` before including any tensorflow files.